# Keep PNG transparency when extracting images from SWF with PHP

Tags: php, png, flash, transparency

I am trying to extract images from SWF. The following code works, but when extracting png images, the background becomes opaque. Any help would be great; this is what I have:

```
class SWFextractImages {
private $swf;
private $jpegTables;
private $shipID;

public function doExtractImages($shipID, $b) {
    $this->shipID = $shipID;
    $this->swf = new SWF($b);
    $this->jpegTables = '';
    foreach ($this->swf->tags as $tag) {
        if($tag['type']==6){
            if($this->defineBits($tag)){
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

private function defineBits($tag) {
    $ret = $this->swf->parseTag($tag);
    $imageData = $ret['imageData'];
    if (strlen($this->jpegTables) > 0) {
        $imageData = substr($this->jpegTables, 0, -2) . substr($imageData, 2);
    }
    if($ret['characterId']==5){
        $filename = sprintf('images/'.$this->shipID.'.jpg', $ret['characterId']);
        file_put_contents($filename, $imageData);
        return true;
    }
    }

}
```

Not sure if this will help, but this extracts other data from SWF file too. [Here's the source code](http://justpaste.it/gydb).

Answer (score 0):

The function defineBits is only for jpg images

For png try this:

```
private function defineBitsLossless($tag) {
$ret = $this->swf->parseTag($tag);

$bitmapFormat = $ret['bitmapFormat'];
$bitmapWidth = $ret['bitmapWidth'];
$bitmapHeight = $ret['bitmapHeight'];
$pixelData = $ret['pixelData'];

$img = imageCreateTrueColor($bitmapWidth, $bitmapHeight);

if ($bitmapFormat == 3) {
    $colorTable = $ret['colorTable'];

    // Construct the colormap
    $colors = array();
    $i = 0;
    $len = strlen($colorTable);
    while ($i < $len) {
    $red = ord($colorTable[$i++]);
    $green = ord($colorTable[$i++]);
    $blue = ord($colorTable[$i++]);
    $colors[] = imageColorAllocate($img, $red, $green, $blue);
    }

    $bytesPerRow = $this->alignTo4bytes($bitmapWidth * 1); // 1 byte per sample

    // Construct the image
    for ($row = 0; $row < $bitmapHeight; $row++) {
    $off = $bytesPerRow * $row;
    for ($col = 0; $col < $bitmapWidth; $col++) {
        $idx = ord($pixelData[$off++]);
        imageSetPixel($img, $col, $row, $colors[$idx]);
    }
    }
} else if ($bitmapFormat == 4) {
    $bytesPerRow = $this->alignTo4bytes($bitmapWidth * 2); // 2 bytes per sample

    // Construct the image
    for ($row = 0; $row < $bitmapHeight; $row++) {
    $off = $bytesPerRow * $row;
    for ($col = 0; $col < $bitmapWidth; $col++) {
        $lo = ord($pixelData[$off++]);
        $hi = ord($pixelData[$off++]);
        $rgb = $lo + $hi * 256;
        $red = ($rgb >> 10) & 0x1f; // 5 bits
        $green = ($rgb >> 5) & 0x1f; // 5 bits
        $blue = ($rgb) & 0x1f; // 5 bits
        $color = imageColorAllocate($img, $red, $green, $blue);
        imageSetPixel($img, $col, $row, $color);
    }
    }
} else if ($bitmapFormat == 5) {
    $bytesPerRow = $this->alignTo4bytes($bitmapWidth * 4); // 4 bytes per sample

    // Construct the image
    for ($row = 0; $row < $bitmapHeight; $row++) {
    $off = $bytesPerRow * $row;
    for ($col = 0; $col < $bitmapWidth; $col++) {
        $off++; // Reserved
        $red = ord($pixelData[$off++]);
        $green = ord($pixelData[$off++]);
        $blue = ord($pixelData[$off++]);
        $color = imageColorAllocate($img, $red, $green, $blue);
        imageSetPixel($img, $col, $row, $color);
    }
    }
}
imagePNG($img, sprintf('images/img_%d.png', $ret['characterId']));
imageDestroy($img);
}
```

You can read more, understand more and use more from [here](https://www.4real.gr/SWFextractImages.php.txt)

Comment: Some problems came up; it seems that the type of the images we're trying to get are 35, which is JPEG3 with guessextension function. We got the images using it, but the images still weren't transparent. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, a .jpg can't be transparent. What's the extension of the images you claim not to be transparent?

Comment: The images are png. It has to be, since they are renders that SWF uses. But when we tested for tag type, it returns 35, which is DefineBitsJPEG3.

Comment: Process your images using the `defineBitsLossless($tag)` function and see what happens.

Comment: I changed the case35 to $ret = $this->parseDefineBitsLosslessTag($bytePosEnd, 1); and forced it to try parsing using losslesstag. I got gzuncompress(): data error.

Comment: Why didn't you change it to `$this->defineBitsLossless($tag);` ?